How and when exactly are `JitCompileTask` triggered to run in Android Runtime?
I could see that JIT Compiler in Android Runtime compiles the method by calling JitCompileTask::Run which is called by ThreadPoolWorker::Run of ThreadPoolWorkers created inside the Runtime environment.
I could also see that the ThreadPoolWorker::Run are in turn called by ThreadPoolWorker::Callback for which I could find no caller in the source code. I could see some ConditionalVariable such as task_queue_condition_ littered throughout the JIT module where ThreadPool::StartWorkers would call ask_queue_condition_.Broadcast(self). But I cannot find any explicit call to callback off the ThreadPoolWorker instance.
